# Trouble passing hash and variable to subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I want to pass a hash and a variable to a subroutine:

```
%HoA = {'1'=>'2'};
my $group_size = 10;

&delete_unwanted(\%HoA,$group_size);

sub delete_unwanted {
    my (%HoA,$group_size) = @_;
    print "'$group_size'\n"
}
```

But, this prints nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a hash reference (as you should), so therefore assign it to a scalar in your parameter catching:

```
sub delete_unwanted {
    my ($hashref, $group_size) = @_;

    print "'$group_size'\n"
}
```

If you later want to dereference it, you can `my %newHoA = %$hashref;`, but that will be a copy of the original hash.  To access the original structure, just use the reference: `print $hashref->{a_key};`.

Comment: Ideally, you'll access the hash through the reference in `$hashref` rather than making a copy of the hash.

Comment: @user2795733 Also note that your original assignment `%HoA = {'1'=>'2'};` is incorrect, but is likely an artifact from you trying solve this problem.  Should be `%HoA = ('1'=>'2');` or `$HoA = {'1'=>'2'};`

Comment: Suppose I deleted a key from the copy of the original hash, would the original hash then be unchanged?

Comment: Yes, [`deleting`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) keys in `%newHoA` would not effect the original `%HoA` that was passed to the subroutine.  You would have to delete keys from the reference to effect the original hash: `delete $hashref->{a_key}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in:

```
my (%HoA,$group_size) = @_;
```

You can solve it by saying, for example:

```
sub delete_unwanted {
    my $hashPointer = shift;
    my $group_size = shift
```

Note that you can retrieve the original hash inside the subroutine by either: de-referencing the hashPointer (my %HoA = %$hashPointer), or you can access the hash contents directly using the pointer directly (eg, $hashPointer->{'key'})

Comment: Is `my $hashPointer = shift; my $group_size = shift;` better than or identical to `my ($hashref, $group_size) = @_;`?

Comment: They're the same (though not sure performance-wise). I prefer shifts since they're more visually appealing than @_ (personal taste).